# magento 1.8 recently viewed products on home page

Tags: magento-1.8

I wanna view "recently viewed products" on home page under list/grid of products for one column view.
I tried various but not achieve. I don't want to use extension as well.
Is there any solutions or links.

Comment: This question is somewhat vague -- you might help people who want to answer you by explaining a big more clearly what you've tried so far to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try add following code to your page content

```
{{widget type="reports/product_widget_viewed" page_size="5" template="reports/widget/viewed/content/viewed_list.phtml"}}
```

Comment: It works thanks, but It shows above products list. I want to display under products list. I think I need some <div>, I am testing but not achieve yet. could you try if you have time please.